What is the name of this "If you fail in the game, you'll die same way" movie?
Years ago (At least, 4-5 years), I watched a movie about a video game which become real in Horror gender, English language and live action.
This is the story I remember: This game was bought by a group of friends from a game-shop and these friends start to play the game. Which of this players fail in the game, the get died in the real life in the same way. for example, as far as I know, one of them died by a carriage in the game and in real life, HE died by the same carriage. and one of them get killed by someone (I think a woman) in his apartment.
At the end, one of them went to a castle-like place and HE did something for the woman (she was like a vampire, It was done by a red flower) and everything end. in the last scene, the game was bought again by a guy in a game-shop (I think it was underground).

This is most likely Stay Alive (2006)

Loomis Crowley is testing the underground game Stay Alive with his
  friends Sarah and Rex. When the game is over, Loomis finds Rex and
  Sarah dead in their room, and he is pushed by a shadow from the
  staircase, breaking the banister and hanging the same way he died in
  the game. Loomis' sister, Emma, gives his game to his best friend,
  Hutch. They, and his friends Miller, Phineus with his sister October,
  Swink and Abigail play the game together. When Miller and Phineus die
  the same way they died in the game, the survivors disclose that the
  game is based on the life of the evil Countess Elizabeth Bathory. She
  was buried alive in the tower of her real state in the Geronge
  Plantation. With the police chasing them, and after the death of
  October, the survivors reach the house and try to find the corpse of
  the Countess to destroy her fiend.

